# Multiple users for a google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm developing a telegram bot that can be used by many users through a google app script.

I tried using `cache.getUserCacheServices()`, because I wanted to let more than one user use the bot simultaneously. I created a log-in feature where by if you type a password you log in. However, this cannot be used simultaneously with two users and when one logs in with the password. The rest also are granted access.

Am I using the function wrongly?
Can anyone give me pointers?

Comment: You can look at the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) to store user specific data and validations.

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi i've read the documentation for properties and cache but i've yet to get an answer that helps me develop a good answer.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The telegram bot webhook points to a GAS web app? Where is the authentication happening? Do the user write the password on the Telegram App or somewhere else? Also, a sample of code would help clarify what your problem is.